# How many ways to place brick on board

Tags: combinatorics

Given - board 5x5 cells, 5 bricks.

1. Assume that all bricks the same.
   How many ways to place bricks on board?
   How many ways to place bricks on board with empty cell left (top left one). Rest cells can be either empty on not.

More than one brick allowed in one cell.

1. All bricks have different colors.

same questions.

Can anyone help me with it? With explanation if possible.

Thanks

Comment: How is this a programming question, exactly?

Comment: Seems more suited for math.stackoverflow.com, or reading your class' text.  (On which note, I suspect this question should have a homework tag :) )

Comment: Not a home work. Just self studying :)

Comment: @paxdiablo there is a way to make a program for NxN board

Comment: So you want to make a program that exhaustively searches a 5x5 grid for all the ways to place 5 bricks?  Mathematical analysis will likely be a better option than a brute force program.

Comment: @sl_bug, if you want a program (or pointers on how to design such a program) for this, you might want to explicitly state that. Otherwise it seems like a logic puzzle, which wouldn't be suitable for SO.

Answer (score 1):

Question:
How many ways can I distinctly put 5 identical bricks on a 5x5 playing board with either 1 or 0 bricks per square?

Answer:
25! / (5! * 20!)

Reason:
The first brick can be put on any of 25 squares, the second on any of 24, the third on any of 23, the fourth on any of 22 and the fifth on any of 21. So there are 25 * 24 * 23 * 22 * 21 ways to place the bricks = 25! / 20!
As the bricks are identical, there are 5! ways of placing them (5 options for place 1, 4 for place 2 etc...) so there are 25! / 20! ways of placing distict bricks and 25! / (5! * 20!) ways of placing identical bricks on a 25x25 board.

Question:
How many ways can I distinctly put 5 identical bricks on a 5x5 playing board with either 1 or 0 bricks per square for all squares except the top left one where there cannot be any bricks?

Answer:
24! / (5! * 19!)

Reason:
This is the same as above, but with only 24 available squares for the bricks.

Question:
How many ways can I put 5 distinct bricks on a 5x5 playing board with either 1 or 0 bricks per square?

Answer:
25! / 20!

Reason: This is explained as the first part of the explanation of question 1.

Question:
How many ways can I put 5 distinct bricks on a 5x5 playing board with either 1 or 0 bricks per square but no bricks in the top left square?

Answer:
24! / 19!

Reason: This is the same problem as the previous question, except that there are only 24 available squares instead of 25.

Question:
How many ways can I put 5 distinct bricks on a 5x5 playing board with 0 - 5 bricks alowed in any square?

Answer:
25 ^ 5

Reason: There are 25 ways to place each of the bricks, so there are 25 * 25 * 25 * 25 * 25 solutions.

Question:
How many ways can I put 5 distinct bricks on a 5x5 playing board with 0 - 5 bricks alowed in any square except the top left square?

Answer:
24 ^ 5

Reason: There are 24 ways to place each of the bricks, so there are 24 * 24 * 24 * 24 * 24 solutions.

Question:
How many ways can I put 5 identical bricks on a 5x5 playing board with 0-5 bricks allowed in any square?

Answer:
(5 + 25 - 1 ) choose 5 = 29 choose 5 = 29! / (5! * 24!)

Reason:
Read up about multinomial cooeficients or google "Number of ways to place n balls in m boxes" for a better explanation.